# Store contents in array before and after matching a pattern

Tags: shell

Contents of file are:

```
1
name
linux
unix
---
he is
going to
learn
4
this is my
second difference
---
how to store
each difference in a variable
```

For every content between ( number (1) and pattern "---") i need to store the values in a array: before and after

example:
echo $before[0]

```
name
linux
unix
```

echo $after[0]

```
he is
going to
learn
```

Now we see the numeral: 4 
now we need to move the index of array and store the contents in them.
echo $before[1]

```
this is my
second difference
```

echo $after[1]

```
how to store
each difference in a variable
```

I'm new to shell. Can you help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Here's the snippet.

```
i=0;
while read line;
do
if grep '[0-9].*' == $line // checks if it starts with a digit
then
$line=$line+1 ( from the next line before " ---" store it in base )
while "$line" != "---"
$line=$line+1
do
base[$i]=$line 
i=$(( i+1 ));
echo $base[$i]
done
fi
done <rit.log
echo "$base"
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. What are the numbers for? Is it the starting index? So `after[1]` is `he is`, `before[5]` is `second difference` and so on or are those numbers meaningless and you simply want all the first sentences (before `---`) to go into `before[0]` and so on?

Comment: I could do this in python, but our servers have very low-end modules of modules. So i gotta stick to shell. I have the logic, stuck since a couple of hours to implement it. Can you please help me?

Comment: the file contents are actually result of ( diff file1 and file2).
the diff result gives the output in that manner. ( line numbers )

Comment: @PesaThe The numbers actually show us the difference in contents of 2 files starting from that line number.
when the number is 1:
the contents followed from 1 till --- ( is the content of file 1)
and the content after " ---" before the next numberal i.e 4 is the content of file 2.

Comment: So they are meaningless basically. And do you need the lines stored in separate array elements or the single element `before[0]` should contain `name\nlinux\nunix` and for example `after[1]` should contain the last two sentences?

Comment: Yes. an index of array can have all the value.
before[0] can have 
name
linux
unix

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

before=() after=()
del=$'\n' is_after=1 i=-1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] && ((i++))
    [[ $line =~ ^([0-9]+|---)$ ]] && { ((is_after=!is_after)); continue; }

    if ((is_after)); then
        after[i]+=$line$del
    else
        before[i]+=$line$del
    fi
done < data

# trim the last delimiter
after=("${after[@]%?}")
before=("${before[@]%?}")
```